# Every Link Becomes formated like Nav Bar in Html

Tags: html, css

When I put in a logo at the top of my page, the logo became formatted like my nav bar.

I believe it has something to do with how I designed my nav bar. I tried to change the formatting on the logo by using inline css but that still didn't work.

---

**My CSS :**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 7;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

h2 {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:impact;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:underline;
} 

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 314px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #21242B;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #4D5365;
}

.divstory {
    background-color:#B33951;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

---

**My HTML :**

```
<body background="webbackground.png">
<a href="index.html"><img src="DTDTMLogo.png" style="width: 180px; margin-bottom: 5px;" ></a>
<hr>
<!--Nav Bar-->
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="index.html" style="color:white;font-size:20px">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="database.html" style="color:white;font-size:20px">Database</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="map.html" style="color:white;font-size:20px">Map</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.papajohns.com/" style="color:white;font-size:20px">About Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- Nav Bar End-->
<hr>
<img alt="When Your In The Action" src="Gamers_in_action1.jpg" style="width:1260px;height:600px;">
<hr>
<h2>Our mission</h2>
<div>
<p>
</body>
```

---

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle, this code gives me all the menu options in a row.

Comment: I don't see anything in your sample code that looks like it would be a logo. Did you accidentally leave that part out?

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6ve2q9en/) @SatejS

Comment: @Elezar Sorry, added the body code.

Comment: I've added a class for your links.So now only that is styled according to the `a` styling you had in place. https://jsfiddle.net/6ve2q9en/1/ Please tell me how you want it from here on.

Comment: @SatejS This works as well. I think I know how to handle it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving all your `a` elements the same styling, because you used selectors like `a:link`, `a:visited`, etc.

To fix this issue, You need to make your selectors more specific.

The easiest way replace this :

```
a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 314px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #21242B;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #4D5365;
}
```

with this :

```
ul a:link, ul a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 314px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #21242B;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul a:hover, ul a:active {
    background-color: #4D5365;
}
```

This would still impact all `a` elements that belong to an `ul` element, though.

To avoid that, consider adding a `class` to your menu, like this :

```
<ul class="main-navigation">
    <li>
        <a href="index.html" style="color:white;font-size:20px">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="database.html" style="color:white;font-size:20px">Database</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="map.html" style="color:white;font-size:20px">Map</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.papajohns.com/" style="color:white;font-size:20px">About Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then, adjust your selectors like this :

```
.main-navigation a:link, .main-navigation a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 314px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #21242B;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-navigation a:hover, .main-navigation a:active {
    background-color: #4D5365;
}
```

This ensures that ONLY your main navigation (or other `a` elements that belong to an element with the class `.main-navigation`) will be impacted.

Comment: I added this code into my website and it worked perfectly! Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: @DreadGeneral : You're welcome. I added some more info on how to further improve your code ;-)

Comment: Again, thank you! This helps a lot and I learned some important information for the future. :)